# Can a woman wear a man's suit jacket if she is cold?

Tags: clothing, tznius-modesty, marit-ayin

Can a woman wear a man's suit jacket if she is cold?

I believe there is a prohibition for a woman to wear man's clothing and wise versa. Would a man's suit jacket fit into this prohibition?

Comment: Why would a man's suit jacket not fit into it? Is it not designed for men? What are you unsure about? You should [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think they mean to say is there an "exception" to this halacha if the person is cold

Comment: @Yehoshua That's not the simple read of his words. It might seem to be the more involved question to someone who knows what Halakhic works have dealt with over the years, but that doesn't mean it's what the OP was asking.

Comment: If it is obvious that she does this for rude cold surely allowed,  but if not,  may depend if she is dangerous to be ill.  If the man walk with the woman and people see that the jacket is his,  there is no confusion an it is allowed.  Comment only

Answer (score -2):

See the gamara in nedarim 49b: R. Judah's wife went out, brought wool, and made an embroidered cloak. On going to market she used to put it on, whilst when R. Judah went [to synagogue] to pray he used to wear it. When he donned it, he uttered the benediction, Blessed be He who hath robed me with a robe.

Comment: This doesnt really answer the question as the robe that they used was probably a gender neutral robe as opposed to a modern mens suit jacket which is not

Comment: Right, as the maharsha explains, this is only mutar by a gender neutral coat; so supposably if the jacet meant in the above question is gender neutral it can defenatly be used for both. and of course if it is a case of pikuach nefesh then either way it should be mutar.